# What's the usage of "slip" in this case?

Tags: meaning

> Step 1: After the water has drained out, check to ensure the power has been restored before you enter. Ensure you are wearing footwear and be careful so as to not ***slip*** on glass or sharp objects.

As per my knowledge slip is nothing but sliding for short distance.
But what is meaning of *slip* here?

Comment: If your foot "slides" out from under you so that your center of gravity is not directly above it you will fall.

Answer (score 2):

Stands for *fall*. You can use footwear but if you get distracted, you can fall straight to the glass or sharp objects as said and hurt yourself.

Comment: Nice.. I got now